# Garbage Collection, super simple example. Will myVariable be cleaned up?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I think this pretty straight forward to someone who understands the GC. Will myVariable be cleaned up?

```js
function a() {
  const myVariable = {
    foo: 'bar'
  };

  b(() => {
    console.log(myVariable);
  });
}

function b(callback) {
  return;
}

a();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cleaned up"? And do you expect it to happen with the current code itself or automatically after its execution?

Comment: @Sébastien it's apparent you don't understand garbage collection if you can't understand his verbiage. His question is as clear as it can be.

Comment: No @sksallaj the question is not that clear. Browsers do [garbage collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) very differently and this is not a function of the JS code but of how the browser implements GC.

Comment: No.. Browers follow a simple mark and sweep algorithm.. Thats the choice of preference after 2012. I'm sorry but I don't understand your argument. He isn't asking about JS function code, he is asking about the GC after running the code.

Comment: I think it makes a difference where this code is executed. Is `a` being declared on the global object or in an IIFE?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I don't think that answer applies anymore, it was answered in 2009, before the mark/sweep algorithm (which handles cyclic references)

Comment: @sksallaj - good catch.I deleted that comment so no one is confused by it.